# Sorting Excel by 4 columns using Python (using win32com?)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, win32com

I've been trying to sort my spreadsheet by 4 columns. Using win32com, I have managed to sort by 3 columns using the below code:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

wb= excel.Workbooks.Open('.xlsx')
ws= wb.worksheets[0]

ws.Range(D6:D110).Sort(Key1=ws.Range('D1'), Order1=1, Key2=ws.Range('E1'), Order2=2, Key3=ws.Range('G1'), Order3=3, Orientation=1)
```

However, when I try to add Key4, it says Key4 is an unexpected keyword argument. Is the Range.Sort function limited to only 3 keys? Is there a way to add a 4th?

Is there maybe another way to do this using pandas or openpyxl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: openpyx will let you set up sort and filter criteria but you will need to open the file in Excel for this to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading in the excel sheet then sorting by header names. This assumes that your excel sheet is formatted correctly like a CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
df = df.sort_values(['key1','key2','key3','key4'], axis=1)
df.to_excel('filename2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Are key1, key2, etc. in this case the column names?

Comment: Yes they are the column names

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort twice or however many times needed in series of three keys.

```
xlAscending = 1
xlSortColumns = 1
xlYes = 1

ws.Range(D6:D110).Sort(Key1=ws.Range('D1'), Order1=xlAscending, 
                       Key2=ws.Range('E1'), Order2=xlAscending, 
                       Key3=ws.Range('G1'), Order3=xlAscending, 
                       header=xlYes, Orientation=xlSortColumns)

# FOURTH SORT KEY (ADJUST TO NEEDED COLUMN)
ws.Range(D6:D110).Sort(Key1=ws.Range('H1'), Order1=xlAscending,
                       header=xlYes, Orientation=xlSortColumns)
```

By the way your *Order* numbers should only be 1, 2, or -4135 per the [xlSortOrder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsortorder) constants.

Comment: I tried the above, but it ended up just resetting the sort bys, and only sorted by H1 in the end, or was there something I missed?

Comment: Hmmm...works on my end. `H1` adds to the other sorts. I compared by just sorting on `H1`.

Comment: The only things I changed were the range as I wanted from D6:I110 and I removed the header as there are no headers in my data, do you think that would have made the difference?